# How to use rxjs defaultIfEmpty on ReplaySubject

Tags: rxjs

Consider this code:

```
const subject = new ReplaySubject<string>();
const observable$ = subject.asObservable();
const result = observable$.pipe(
  map(value => value + 'not empty'),
  defaultIfEmpty('empty')
);
result.subscribe(value => console.log(value));
```

When I run it, I expected to have ***'empty'*** in my browser console logs, but got nothing.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

RxJS documentation tells that about `defaultIfEmpty`:
`Emit given value if nothing is emitted before completion.`

It looks like you need to complete your `Subject`, and then, if there is no emitted value, you will get your `defaultIfEmpty` value.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually, I tried to simplify the code I gave in the question. In the project I am working on, the subject is private, I have only access to the observable.

Comment: @Mchaker On what condition do you think the observable is empty? You can probably encode that. Like if you're hitting a server api and get no response for 10s, it's probably timed out. You can used RxJS's `timeout` or `timeoutWith` for that example.

Comment: @MChaker I can recommend use for example `startWith` operator, it will set default value on start in this case.

Comment: @TonyMarko +1 for this alternative.